# Resolving ATS type error

Tags: ats

Preface this with: learning ATS from the ATS web site.

When trying to pull a record out of a list, once I try to reference the record variable I get a type error on x4.a below.

So why does this fail - wouldn't x4 know it has a record?

```
typedef
abc1_rec = '{a=int, b=int, c=char}
typedef
abc2_rec = '{a=int, b=char, c=string} 

val x1 = '{a=1,b=3,c='A'} : abc1_rec        // boxed record
val x2 = '{a=1,b='B',c="CAT"} : abc2_rec    // boxed record
val a1 = x2.a                               // =1
val x3 = (x2 :: x1 :: list_nil())           // concat list x2 + x1 + nil
val x4  = x3.head()                         // record x2

val x5 = x4.a      // error - [a] cannot be found
```

> /tmp/patsopt_tcats_lu0auT: 1440(line=77, offs=12) -- 1442(line=77,
>   offs=14): error(3): [a] cannot be found: the type [S2EVar(779)] is
>   expected to be a tyrec(record). patsopt(TRANS3): there are [1] errors
>   in total. exit(ATS): uncaught exception:
>   _2home_2hwxi_2Research_2ATS_2dPostiats_2src_2pats_error_2esats__FatalErrorExn(1025)

Answer (score 1):

Note x1 and x2 are of different types. They cannot really be put into the
same list. In this case, the type for x3 is list(X, 2) for some T that is assumed to be a *subtype* of both `abc1_rec` and `abc2_rec`; x4 is of the type T, and x4.a gives you a type-error because the typechecker cannot infer that T is a record type.

Comment: For that, you can just write `val x3 = $list{abs1_rec}(x2, x1)`

Comment: Or you can write `val x3 = list_cons(x2, list_cons(x1, list_nil{abs1_rec}())`

Comment: Thank you that helps. If I use all the same type "abc1_rec" would val x3 = (x2 :: x1 :: list_nil()) give me list(abc1_rec,2)? Where :: is redefining list_cons.

Comment: I see where you can use {T} suffix on list_ functions to keep the type designation. ex)  val v3 = list_cons{tdef1}(v2,v3)